# Printf only printing one word from scanf input in c

Tags: c, char, scanf

I wrote and compiled this program in codeblocks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char myChar[155];
    scanf("%s", myChar);
    printf("%s\n", myChar);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried many things but for some reason when you input a string with more than one word, the console only outputs the first word. Is it the fault of the compiler or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You're doing something wrong. You should probably read the documentation to see what `%s` actually does. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: That's how `scanf` with `%s` works. It only stores _one_ [whitespace separated] word. To input a whole line string such as: `Mauser Maschine` [`scanf` will only get `Mauser`], use `fgets` [and strip the newline]. Then, you'll have the full string [with the spaces]. In other words, try: `fgets(myChar,sizeof(myChar),stdin); myChar[strcspn(myChar,"\n")] = 0;`

Comment: The `f` part of `scanf` is there for a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch to

```
scanf("%154[^\n]", myChar);
```

`154` to avoid buffer overflows - `[^\n]` scans until a new line.

or better yet, use `fgets` and strip the trailing new line:

```
if (fgets(myChar, sizeof myChar, stdin))
{
    myChar[strcspn(myChar, "\n")] = '\0';
}
```

Notice that `scanf` and `fgets` can fail, in such case you end up printing an uninitialized value (undefined behaviour), to avoid problems with the standard input always initialize your strings:

```
char myChar[155] = "";
```

Comment: Thx for responding guys. I don't know how to close a question so see ya!

Comment: @Mauser_Maschine [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Too bad they left so soon, they were very pretty :P

Comment: @DavidRanieri Are you talking about the fake profile picture? I was just trying to get your answer accepted :D

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I apreciate it, and yes, I was talking about the profile picture :D

Comment: It aint fake. It's american 

Comment: @Mauser_Maschine It _is_ a nice picture. But, the aspect ratio is off. So, you're getting a very tall but very thin image (e.g.) The source seems to be widescreen 16:9 that got incorrectly converted to 4:3 to fit the square box area.

Comment: @Craig Estey, Thx, now I can appropriately resize my b00b images. I can't believe I would be getting b00b pic advice on stack overflow. Respect to you, sir